# Upload script returning blank data

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify, rapidshare

I have the Uploadify jQuery plugin set up on my site to manage file uploads. Within the `onUploadSuccess` event, I have this code:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
    console.log("Upload complete for file " + file.name + ". Script returned: " + data);
}
```

This is meant to show me whatever the upload script spits out. Now, usually the response is something like this:

> Upload complete for file test.jpg. Script returned:
>   {"status":1,"file":{"id":"v8rwlxj3","name":"test.jpg"}}

The upload script is first accepting the file, then uploading it to Rapidshare using cURL like so:

```
// Move uploaded file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $targetDir . '/' . $id);

// Get the RapidShare server to upload to
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=nextuploadserver');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
if(!$uploadServer = trim(curl_exec($ch))) {
    error('nextuploadserver failed');
}
if(strstr($uploadServer, 'ERROR:')) {
    error('nextuploadserver failed');
}

// Upload the file to RapidShare
$uploadID = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
$url = 'http://rs' . $uploadServer . '.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?uploadid=' . $uploadID;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$postFields = array('sub' => 'upload',
                    'login' => 'login',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'uploadid' => $uploadID,
                    'filename' => $_FILES['Filedata']['name'],
                    'filecontent' => '@' . $targetDir . '/' . $id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
if(!$resp = curl_exec($ch)) {
    error('upload call failed');
}
```

when it's uploaded, the upload script spits out a JSON response like so:

```
// Output
echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'file' => array('id' => $id, 'name' => $uploadDetails[1])));
```

This works fine for smaller files. When I upload my 30MB test file however, I get this response:

> Upload complete for file 30mb.txt. Script returned:

At first I thought PHP was hitting the max execution time, but I have this at the top of my script:

```
set_time_limit(21600); // 6 hours
```

And besides, I'd see the PHP error being returned. But it's just not returning *anything*. What could cause this? Thanks.

Comment: PHP may be not hitting time limit, but ajax may be reaching connection timeout while waiting for the response

Comment: Ah, that may be it. Uploadify assumes the upload was successful if it doesn't receive a response back from the script after 30 seconds. I'll set the success timeout to something high then see if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) is set to above 30M? That one has caused me some headaches in the past.

Comment: Yeah, the large files still get uploaded to Rapidshare and they're stored in my local directory so I know for a fact that the uploads are working. It just seems that the script is returning prematurely (the upload to Rapidshare is still running after the script has "returned").

Answer (score 0):

PHP may be not hitting time limit, but ajax may be reaching connection timeout while waiting for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Remove uploadid post parameter. Uploadid parameter with resume upload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes nice answer, although it was in comment but helped me.
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/successtimeout/

set successTimeout to some high value. lets say 1 hour.